# Does BEGIN statement starts a new transaction in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I perform the following operations in Redshift -

1. COPY from S3 to a temp table
2. BEGIN
3. more commands...

I see that that no new transaction is created after the begin and the commands continue running under the transaction of the COPY command. Does this make sense?

I use JDBC driver 1.2.8. Saw a different behavior in 1.1.7.

Is this by any chance changed in the driver? (didn't find any connection though)

Doc - 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/Amazon+Redshift+JDBC+Release+Notes.pdf

Comment: Sounds like you have a different `autocommit` setting since the change in driver.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This is the reason indeed. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a different autocommit setting since the change in driver.